# Go and multiline argument hell

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, pg

I was writting a wraper/validator over pg in go when I came upon a rather annoying thing... passing very long strings as argument.
Basically I have this string:

```
"UPDATE " + m["table"] + "_tags SET keys = keys || ," + strconv.Itoa(key) + " WHERE tag = " + t + ";" + "INSERT INTO "  m["table"] + "_tags (tag,keys) SELECT '" + t + "', '" + strconv.Itoa(key) + ") WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + m["table"]"_tags WHERE tag = " + t + ");"
```

Ok, big, unweildy, full of ' and  "... hell on earth.
But that's how SQL queries look an quite frankly I can't think of a better way of dynamically composing them.

So In a reasonable language like C++ this would simply work.
In JavaScript I'd add "\" at the end of each... etc

Is there such a mechanic in go ?
I previously heard that adding "," at the end of each line is the equivalent of \ in javascript but the documentation for this seems to be rather poorly written and most examples online cite things like:

"Change your SQL query" (doable, but not exactly the solutiuon I want from a low-level language).
"Use ' at the beginning and end"... but since there's no way to escape ' inside of ' that would be kind of hard (adding an additional 6* + operators) and I'm quite unsure if wrapping with ' works when I have + concatenations inside.
Suggestions ?

(Best I can come up with is construct the string outside the argument but once again that seems hack-ish)

Comment: "In a reasonable language" - your code snippet is ignoring good security practices regardless of language. Go not allowing it is a good thing.

Comment: Wait, why ? Those values aren't entered directly from the user's input, they pass a validity check (and some formatting beforehand). Should you guard against the SQL injection "inside" the queries ?

Comment: Perhaps your upstream formatting/validation is sufficient for making this safe, I can't really say based on what's here. That code smells though. I'm sure there are some better ways of doing this, even if they're a bit more work. I would recommend against this dynamic query assembly for the sake of complexity alone. Wait til you have a defect and you're looking through the db's logs to see what queries were executed then trying to reproduce them in your app with specific inputs that cause it to form that query. You're better off with 10 sprocs than one 100 line function to generate queries imo

Answer (score 0):

Create a template:

```
`UPDATE %s_tags SET keys = keys || %d WHERE tag = %d; INSERT INTO %s ...;`
```

Then pass in the parameters.

P.S. This can be vulnerable to ingestion attack, verify the values before plugging them in.

Comment: Thanks, answer I was looking for, Silly me forgot those were actually a thing. I guess that's what happens to my brain after using too many scripting languages...